# How do I declare and call array in PARI/GP?

Tags: arrays, pari-gp

How do I declare and call array in PARI/GP?

For example, I have the following in java:

```
int[] myArray = new int[5];
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
   myArray[i] = i + 5;
}
```

How do I do the same thing while using PARI/GP?

Comment: Seems to be covered here: http://hyperpolyglot.org/computer-algebra#arrays

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The usual way is

```
myArray = vector(5, i, i+4);
```

where I have replaced `i+5` with `i+4` because GP vectors are 1-based, not 0-based.

You could also do

```
myArray = vector(5);
for(i=1,5, myArray[i] = i+4);
```

if you prefer. (This is useful in some cases, e.g., when you want to refer to earlier values in the array.)

Answer (score -2):

```
x = [];
for (i=1,10, print("test " i ": " x[i]))
```

Comment: Hi it doesn't work when accessing `x[1]` (apparently `x=[];` doesn't allocate any memory for the array)